# Разбор пьесы по ролям через словари (Python)

Tags: python, словари

Нужна помощь! Необходимо из текстового файла разобрать пьесу по ролям(включая слова автора) таким образом:

До:

```
Кристофер Слай: Ну ясно! — Как мне звать ее?
Лорд: Мадам.
Кристофер Слай: Мадама Элс или мадама Джон?
Лорд: Мадам — и все. Так жен зовут вельможи
```

После:

```
Кристофер Слай: 
Ну ясно! — Как мне звать ее?
Мадама Элс или мадама Джон?
Лорд: Мадам.
Мадам — и все. Так жен зовут вельможи.
```

При этом текстовый файл нельзя заранее форматировать перед чтением самой программой.

Сам я начал с такого кода, в котором читается и выводится файл, но отсутствует сам алгоритм, так как не знаю с чего начать:

```
#Чтение файла
def read_file():
    read_success = False
    result = []
    while(not read_success):
        filename = input("Insert your file:")
        try:
            result = open(filename, encoding="utf-8").readlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found!")
            continue
        if result == []:
            print('File is empty!')
            continue
        try:
            result = list(map(str, map(lambda a: a[:-1],result)))
        except ValueError:
            print("There's nothing to read!")
            continue
        read_success = True
    return result
#Алгоритм
def piece (a):

#Вывод файла
A = read_file()
print(A)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
opera ='Кристофер Слай: Ну ясно! — Как мне звать ее?\n' \
       'Лорд: Мадам.\n' \
       'Кристофер Слай: Мадама Элс или мадама Джон?\n' \
       'Лорд: Мадам — и все. Так жен зовут вельможи'
rol = {'Кристофер Слай': [], 'Лорд': []}

line_text = opera.splitlines()
for text in line_text:
    s_text = text.split(': ')
    d = rol[s_text[0]]
    d.append(s_text[1])
    rol[s_text[0]] = d

for i in rol:
    print(f'{i}:')
    for x in rol[i]:
        print(x)
    print()
```

Peзультат:

```
Кристофер Слай:
Ну ясно! — Как мне звать ее?
Мадама Элс или мадама Джон?

Лорд:
Мадам.
Мадам — и все. Так жен зовут вельможи
```

Comment: А что делать в случае, чтобы код читал именно текстовый файл с полной версией пьесы(https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pxoal83oxn239y/roles.txt?dl=0), где имеется множество ролей и слов соответственно?

Comment: Ну как-то так: https://disk.yandex.kz/d/ftcCuFbaY2d6Xg